# Set rotation point of Rectangle

Tags: qt, rotation, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Is there a way to set rotation point in `Rectangle` and simply use rotation property without any other additional component? I want to rotate a `Rectangle` with binding property of `rotation: value * 180` like this

```
Rectangle{
    id: body
    rotation: value
    anchors.centerIn: parent.Center
    antialiasing: true
}
onValueChanged: body.rotation = value
```

I got only rotation around the left upper corner of parent. Please help me to understand this behavior or suggest me another way to implement rotation on the center.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rotation` property rotates item clockwise around its `transformOrigin` property which could be one of these nine points :

[image]

So you can rotate around one of them like :

```
Rectangle{
    id: body
    rotation: value
    transformOrigin: Item.Center
    anchors.centerIn: parent.Center
    antialiasing: true
}
```

If you want to rotate around an arbitrary point you should use `Rotation` transform type :

```
Rectangle{
    id: body
    transform: Rotation { origin.x: 25; origin.y: 25; angle: value}
    anchors.centerIn: parent.Center
    antialiasing: true
}
```